# Symfony 2 Quiz style

Tags: symfony-2.3

I want to make a quiz(really simple one) for my student. I have 2 entity one question and one answer with a relation onetomany frome answer entity.
I want to be able to write the questions for a tex X and put all of them in a page with a field answer.

Exemple:
1) question 1

```
<input name question1>
```

2) question 2

```
<input name question2>
```

I did this for the moment:

```
public function newAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('AdminQuizBundle:Question')->findAll();

    $questions = array();
    $forms = array();

    foreach ($entities as $question) {
        $entity = new Reponse();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ReponseType(), $entity);

        $questions[] = $question; 
        $forms[] = $form->createView();
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $forms,
        'questions' => $questions,
    );


}
```

it works but went i try to save just the last one did

Comment: I can't see the part that is performing the database inserts.  The createAction() maybe?

Comment: Yes i use the crud to generate my view.

Comment: What you want is having different questions on one form, right? [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: yes exact but with this code it work the problem is to save it